# How to show other users information (such as photos or usernames) using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I'm currently working on an Firebase android application, and after doing some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103407/am-i-able-to-load-another-users-profile-image-in-firebase-android) it seems that Firebase doesn't allow apps to display user information other than the logged in user, for security reasons.

I would like to know then what are some secure ways to do so, or how is it usually done, because what is the point of having profile pictures and other information if you can't show them to other users anyway?

For example, should I save a profile picture copy on Firebase Storage for each user? How should I link the actual images to their corresponding user? What about other relevant information about the user, should I create a "User" node in firebase database that somehow links to the original user in "authentication"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Should I save a profile picture copy on Firebase Storage for each user ?* **Yes**
2. *How should I link the actual images to their corresponding user ?* You can create a folder Users and then for each user create a folder with their userid that uniquely identifies each user. In other words, you can create a Firebase storage structure like this :

   Users
     |_userid
       |_picture
3. *Should I create a "User" node in firebase database that somehow links to the original user in "authentication"?* **Of course** if you want to store and get user's information. Just avoid to store passwords and emails.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. How about the app being secure, would I be making it any less safe with this approach?

Comment: To improve database security and data privacy you can always add database rules (Both for realtime database and storage). With those, you can control who can access which data. I highly recommend you to look at the documentation here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: @Arrabidas92 Good answer. Two minor additions. The users email is stored within their user object in Firebase and can always be retrieved with *String email = user.getEmail();*. The same thing for their profile pic - it doesn't need to managed separately; the url can be retrieved from the user object with *Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();* See [Manage Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Comment: @Jay I believe that only works for the current user, my question was about how to do that with every user in the database